# My Lubuntu installation black screens only after loading configurations. How do I fix it from recovery mode terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, driver, nvidia

I have a multi-boot installation on my computer, 2 Lubuntus and a Win10.
After upgrading my GPU, only one of the installations of Lubuntus started having problems.

I can see the boot loader, I can see the boot screen, and after that, I am sent into a blackscreen with
a cursor.
At first, it is at 60 fps.
Then, normally it flashes and switches to 144fps, by reading a configuration file.
The problem, is that now it stops recognizing my screen after that part.

**What I've tried:**

Ctrl-alt-F1 ~ 3 on an attempt to get the terminal: Did not work. Screen still black.

Recovery mode dpkg: Fixed a few packages, when rebooted did not fix anything.

Recovery mode -> maintenance mode -> ubuntu-drivers autoinstall : Installed new drivers successfully. I expected this to work, but it did not. Problem persists.

Googling how to reset graphics settings: Tried a few answers. All of them were near-misses to my problem.

I am pretty sure all I have to do is reset the graphics settings, since it does recognize the screen at first. Any help on how to do it is appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question. I suggest deleting it here and posting in [ubuntu.se].

Comment: I am aware of that rule, but many similar questions are left unclosed as long as it mentions or is related to scripts or the terminal.  
I thought this question would also be on-topic?

Comment: It's not just that it's off topic here. You're more likely to get useful help in [ubuntu.se]. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic